# Android getContentResolver query not finding DISPLAY_NAME

Tags: android, android-contacts

I have an Android app that needs to pull a list of contacts and phone numbers from the user's stored contacts on the phone.  This has worked fine for the last year or so.  However, last week a user reported that the app was crashing on this page.  The stack trace pointed to this code

```
String[] projection = new String[] { ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER, 
                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME };

Cursor cursor = p_context.getContentResolver().query(
                ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, 
                projection, 
                null,
                null, 
                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME.toUpperCase())
```

The exception message reads:

```
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: DİSPLAY_NAME (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, has_phone_number, display_name FROM view_contacts_restricted WHERE ((1)) ORDER BY DİSPLAY_NAME
```

Everything I've been able to find looks like the DISPLAY_NAME field should be available here.  Any idea why this one user is suffering from this issue?  According to Google Analytics, he is running Android version 4.2.2.  I do not know if this is a modded rom or not.